# what is the difference between sass watch and compass watch

Tags: sass

For sass currently I am using

```
sass --watch path1:path2
```

to compile scss file to css but i even found

```
compass watch path1:path2
```

also. Is there any difference between these two watches? I created a project with `compass create project` and found that there are two main folders called `sass` and `stylesheets` I looked to `screen.scss` file and I found the code `@import "compass/reset";`, but there isn't any directory called `compass` to call the reset.

I am really new to sass and compass. Can anyone explain me how to use compass? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To understand the difference, you must first understand the difference between Sass and Compass.

- **Sass** is a language which is an extension of CSS. It has built in math functions and adds the ability to add more functions and `mixins` - but it doesn't include any.
- **Compass** is a framework for Sass. It adds additional functionality on *top* of Sass such as CSS3 mixins, layout helpers and other utilities. It also gives you the ability to add additional 3rd party frameworks into your project (called [extensions](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/)).

So with that, the difference between the two are:

- **sass --watch** will compile Sass files, but because it doesn't know anything about compass, it will just ignore it.
- **compass watch** is just like the Sass command, only it knows about the additional Compass functionality. So when you import `compass/reset` - it knows what to import.

You can find a reference to all Compass' functionality here: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/

At the top of each page it will show you which part of Compass to import. For example, here is the page about `reset`: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/reset/

Comment: It means sass --watch isn't necessary if we use compass right ?

Comment: would it be more correct to say that Sass is a superset of CSS if Sass can compile any given traditional CSS?

Comment: @AlonAmir correct. Sass have updated their definition to use 'extension' instead, so I'll use that.

Comment: @AlonAmir to be precise, SCSS is a superset of CSS. Sass has also an older syntax called simply SASS that is not.